# Error parsing json in my Android app

Tags: java, json, android-listview

While parsing JSON data from a server on my Android application, I get the following error:

```
org.json.json exception value <html><head><title>Apache of type java.lang.String cannot conveted to JSONObject
```

Does anybody know what's causing the problem?

Comment: Check the response you are getting back. "<html><head><title>Apache" is not json.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is a `JSONException`. According to json.org's [JSON in Java](http://www.json.org/java/index.html) (since the Javadoc isn't as helpful):

> A JSONException is thrown when a syntax or procedural error is detected.

The data you're trying to parse is not of the [JSON format](http://www.json.org/). It looks like it's HTML. It's possible this is caused by you querying an invalid url, which is returning an error page in HTML instead of the JSON you expect.

A JSON object would look like this:

```
{
    "foobar": "some value here",
    "bla": "maybe another thing here",
    "sub-document": {
        "whatever": "lorem ipsum"
    }
}
```